# How do I scroll?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

How do I scroll up and down? **Not panning** with the middle mouse button, just moving my perspective up the x-, y-, or z-axis. So that there is no rotation involved like with the middle mouse button. 
Please help, the objects that I'm rendering are quite large, and I can't edit the top or bottom at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried shift + mmb or ctrl + scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like float said, it is likely <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd>.

You could have your settings changed though, those are simply the defaults. Check your input settings here:

[image]